# Do I have to install Lua in order to compile with LuaTex? Which is the best way to do it?

Tags: luatex, installing, lua

I've already installed TeXLive and TexMaker. Now I'm thinking of turning to LuaTeX. What are the steps I have to follow in order to start compiling with LuaTeX? Do I have to install Lua first? If so, which is the best way to do it on Windows 10? Out of the many github repositories dedicated to this purpose (e.g. [rjpcomputing/luaforwindows](https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows) or [luarocks/luarocks/wiki/installation-instructions-for-windows](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/installation-instructions-for-windows)) which one is the most reliable?

Comment: As TeXnician noted, you do not have to install Lua, because the stuff you need is already included when you install LuaTeX (LuaLaTeX) with TeXLive. The Lua support is within TeXLive, not at the top level of your hard drive. And, you do not need to know any Lua programming (unless you want to), because the vital Lua code is already contained in `fontspec` and some other packages you will use. I use LuaLaTeX exclusively, and do not know a whit of Lua. Once in a while, I copy and paste some Lua code posted on these forums, if it does something remarkable.

Comment: A significant aspect of Lua is that it was designed from scratch for embedded systems and clients. Thus, LuaTeX is a TeX engine that embeds a (nearly full) Lua, version 5.2, at present. (Alas, not yet version 5.3; hopefully, though, this will change in the not too distant future.) A main reason for why Lua, rather than some other programming language, was chosen was precisely that it's easily embedded in other programs (such as the LuaTeX executable).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to install Lua separately in order to run `luatex`. If you have installed TeX Live (the usual install is the full install) you will have it on your machine. If you want to double-check use `texlua --version` in the command line of your operating system.

Comment: Until now, I did not realize that `texlua` was an alias for `luatex`. Users might prefer `lualatex`.

Comment: @RobtAll Maybe, but the OP asked for luatex. Why bother with the format if you consider switching engines?

Comment: Maybe "asked for luatex" really meant "should asked for lualatex." Not so much a switch, as a clarification.

Comment: @RobtAll `texlua` isn't really an alias it accepts lua rather than tex code in that mode.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I learned something new. I tried command line to get the version, and both `textlua` and `luatex` provided the same reply (Ubuntu). So I thought maybe they were the same, via hard link.

Comment: @RobtAll they are but so are all of latex and tex and pdflatex and pdftex, the program name affects the behaviour, so it's odd to call them aliases